# Byte[] data changes after saved to SQL with Java

Tags: java, sql, encryption, byte

```
 public void saveNewAccount(String name, String username, byte[] pas, byte [] salt) {
    try {
        Class.forName(myUrl);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(myDriver);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pas)+ "before save");
        String sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PASSWORDSALT) " +
                "VALUES ('"+name+"','"+username+"','"+pas+"','"+salt+"');";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public List<byte[]> getAccountPas(String username) {
    List<byte[]> acc = null;
    try {
        acc = new ArrayList<>();
        Class.forName(myUrl);
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(myDriver);
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (USERNAME='"+username+"');");
        while (rs.next()) {
            acc.add(rs.getBytes("PASSWORDSALT"));
            acc.add(rs.getBytes("PASSWORD"));
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(acc.get(0))+ "salt sql");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(acc.get(1)) + "pas from sql");
        }
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return acc;
}
```

So I have problem here.
After I get my password from database it differs from version I saved. 
But salt is still same. 
I spend today to figure out, but I couldn't found solution. 
Thanks to everyone who will try to help. :)

Comment: http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/   and also, don't construct sql queries by concatenating strings. It's a security hole and you run into quoting issues, which is probably what's happening in your case. Use parametrized queries/prepared statements.

Comment: I note you have a semicolon `;` more in the end in both of your query, try to remove them like this:
        
      "INSERT INTO...."'"
      "SELECT * FROM ..."'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DO NOT** use string concatenation to build a SQL statement with values from an external source (e.g. user). The SQL statement will fail with syntax error if a value contains `'`, or worse, the code is simply asking to be hacked using [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), allowing hackers to steal your data and/or delete your tables.

As for the problem you're seeing, of course the database doesn't contain the values you were trying to save. Byte arrays like `pas` and `salt` will be something like this when concatenated with strings:

```
[B@659e0bfd
```

So you SQL is:

```sql
INSERT INTO accounts (NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PASSWORDSALT)
VALUES ('John Doe','jdoe','[B@2a139a55','[B@659e0bfd');
```

The solution for both issues mentioned above (SQL Injection and byte arrays) is the same: Use `PreparedStatement`.

Note: Remove the extraneous `;` at the end of the SQL statement. Don't end SQL statements with `;`. Also changed to use try-with-resources, for better resource cleanup handling.

```java
public void saveNewAccount(String name, String username, byte[] pas, byte [] salt) {
    try (Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("")) {
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        String sql = "INSERT INTO accounts (NAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, PASSWORDSALT)" +
                    " VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        try (PreparedStatement stmt = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, username);
            stmt.setBytes (3, pas);
            stmt.setBytes (4, salt);
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            c.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I note you have a semicolon `;` more in the end in both of your query, try to remove them like this:

```
  "INSERT INTO...."'"
  "SELECT * FROM ..."'"
```

Comment: You should add it as a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!